# How to match true and false using TextFormatter in java

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

Some backstory. I am using textformatting to filter input into a textfield. I have one for numbers only, one for alphanumeric characters, one for numbers with decimal. This should ne letters only, and only match "true" or "false" case insensitive. The code I have below will allow ONLY those letters to be typed, which is functionality I want, but it will not match in order.

```
UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filterBoolean = (TextFormatter.Change t) -> {
                        if (t.isReplaced()) {
                            if (t.getText().matches("[^tTrRuUFfAaLlSsEe]")) {
                                t.setText(t.getControlNewText().substring(t.getRangeStart(), t.getRangeEnd()));
                            }
                        } else if (t.isAdded()) {
                            if (t.getText().matches("[^tTrRuUFfAaLlSsEe]")) {
                                t.setText("");
                            } else if (t.getText().matches("[^tTrRuUFfAaLlSsEe]")) {
                                t.setText("");
                            }
                        }
                        return t;
                    };
getTextField().setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(formatter));
```

I have tried to use this functionality by separating them adding

```
|| t.getControlNewText().matches("[tT][rR][uU][eE]|[fF][aA][lL][sS][eE]")
|| t.getControlNewText().matches("[^([tT][rR][uU][eE]|[fF][aA][lL][sS][eE])]")
|| t.getControlNewText().matches("^([tT][rR][uU][eE]|[fF][aA][lL][sS][eE])")
```

to each t.getText() line, but it does not seem to work.
I have similiar text formatters that will allow any alphanumeric character up to X times, but those are not order sensitive.

So my question is, how can I edit my code to allow for order sensitive input of a textfield, where I only want to match "true" and "False", case insensitive?

Comment: Mostly off-topic, but I find it hard to envision a use case for this. If the user is supposed to enter "true" or "false", why not just use a check box, radio button, or toggle button?

Comment: Well you could shift the text to be lowercase for starters.  Also I'm not sure why you can't just use `Boolean.parseBoolean(someString)` if you're set on getting this from a `String`.

Comment: The textfield are being dynamically added to an Editor, but that is a good idea.

Comment: Using a regex for this is very overkill. Just check the string manually.

Comment: I dont want the user to be able to enter anything other than true or false, in the letter order. @SusannahPotts

Comment: @SusannahPotts The first point is excellent, of course. But checking by parsing won't work, because the validation is performed on every change in the text. If the user is changing the text from `"true"` to `"false"`, the entire sequence, which might be something like `"tru"`, `"tr"`, `"t"`, `""`, `"f"`, `"fa"`, etc, needs to pass the validation.

Comment: @James_D fair point.  That's why I said I wasn't sure.  Though, this is an atrocious way to go about doing this.  You're absolutely right that this should be a toggle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comment, you should almost certainly consider using a different control for this, such as a check box or other kind of toggle button.

If you want to go this route, you need to think about what would be valid *while the user is still editing* (not just when editing is complete). So, e.g. the user might delete from any position in the text `"true"` or `"false"`. Conceivably, they might also start typing, say `"true"` before deleting `"false"`.

So you probably want something like

```
UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filterBoolean = (TextFormatter.Change t) -> {
    String testText = t.getControlNewText().toLowerCase();
    if ("truefalse".contains(testText) || "falsetrue".contains(testText)) {
        return t ;
    }
    // otherwise veto:
    return null ;
};
```

If you wanted to be a bit stricter (but probably more annoying for the user), you could just do `if ("true".contains(testText) || "false".contains(testText))`, etc. You could be even more sophisticated, e.g. you could delete *all* the text if there is any delete operation (since that is likely the intention of the user).

In either case, you would then need additional validation when the user commits (probably on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or on loss of keyboard focus).

Again, it's a much better user experience just to use a control specifically designed for this use case.

Comment: This does exactly what I need it do. I'm still new at this, thank you!